# Deleting zero before decimal point in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

This might be a very basic question. I need to remove the zero before decimal point and print it that way. For example if I have 0.8 it should show .8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formatting provided by the ToString method to clip away the integer part if it is 0

```
Dim x as Decimal = 0.8
Dim textToPrinto = x.ToString(".####")
```

(This keeps 4 decimals if present before rounding)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a StreamWriter or printing output to a file, then you can also use the Format statement.  Format is used in a MsgBox example below (place in a Button command), which is identical for using in a sw or Print, Printline command.

```
   Dim x As Double = 0.8
   'You can remove zeroes after the decimal below
   MsgBox(Format(x, ".0000"))
   MsgBox(Format(x, ".0"))
```